How to create a table of contents where same elements are grouped with their page numbers separated by commas?
I want to create a table of so-called "OSO Markers" with their respective page numbers separated by commas. Here is an example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listosoname}{List of OSO Markers}
\newlistof{oso}{looso}{\listosoname}
\newcommand{\oso}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{oso}
\noindent\textbf{\textcolor{red}{\#OSO #1}}
\addcontentsline{looso}{oso}{\#OSO #1}}
\begin{document}
\listofoso
\newpage
\oso{1}
\newpage
\oso{2}
\oso{1}
\newpage
\oso{2}
\oso{1}
\end{document}

This compiles to:

but I would like it to look like this:

Thanks in advance for any help.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

I think you will be better of to make these markers as a special index, then they can be sorted both by name and page numbers. An index doesnt have to go at the back it can also go in the front.

@yannisl Thank you, that is a very good suggestion. I will look into it and share my results if I get it to work.
